# SAS Ods RTF and PROC REPORT

Tags: sas

So I've writen this:

```
ods rtf file = "D:\Sarath\List\2.rtf";
    proc report data = list.lst1;   
    column PATIENT EOSDT STDRUG STDRUGSP STDCOMP STDCOMSP DAY5 EOSREAS;
    define PATIENT/display   "Subject * Number";
    define EOSDT /order  "Date of * Study Completion/ * Early Discontinuation";
    define STDRUG/order   "Administered*Study Drug?";
    define STDRUGSP/display "If no,*Specify" ;
    define STDCOMP/order "Completed*Dosing";
    define STDCOMSP/display "If no,*Specify";
    define DAY5/order "Completed*Study?";
    define EOSREAS/display "Reason for * not Completing";
    run;
 ods rtf close;
```

and it creates an rtf with no data. Just a blank page. Please tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Regards.

Comment: What does the SAS log state?

Comment: no problems in the log

NOTE: There were 48 observations read from the data set LIST.LST1.
NOTE: PROCEDURE REPORT used (Total process time):
      real time           32.38 seconds
      cpu time            1.45 seconds

Comment: Is there output in the SAS results window, either listing or HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Add nowd to the proc report line, otherwise SAS is expecting proc report to be an interactive procedure.

```
proc report data = list.lst1 nowd;
```

See documentation here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473620.htm